# How to know how many event listeners there are on the page

Tags: javascript

I am building a fairly large application in Javascript. It is a single page that can change different views. All the views have their own variables, events, listeners, elements, etc.

When working with large collections and multiple events it's sometimes good to know what exactly is happening on the page.

I know all the browsers have developer tools, but sometimes it's hard to click trough all the elements etc. And some options I can not find.

One thing I am interested in is to know how many events there currently listened for on the page. This way I can confirm that I am not creating zombies.

If the sollution is a developer tool, please let me know where to look and what to do. And most important, which browser to choose.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/446892/206403

Comment: This answer by [Andrew Hedges][1] might help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node

Comment: @luso: When posting comments, the markdown syntax is slightly different (click the "help" button to the right of the textbox).

Comment: Thank you Rocket. It is actually a "trivial answer converted to comment" by the system.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best way to do this in Chrome is to use [`getEventListeners`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#geteventlisteners), which is part of the devtools API. (Note: this is only accessible to a developer in devtools, not accessible to a normal script in a page.)

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('*')` to grab all elements on a page, and run them each through `getEventListeners` to get their event listeners. [Another answer by Mr.Raindrop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45842644/710446) has several suggestions and approaches of how to do this in practice.

Comment: Great, I like this approuch. Will this also catch custom events that I create with jQuery, for example `myVar.on('customEventxx', this.doSomething)`.

Comment: Yes, it does; I just tested.  However, I've just realized a significant problem: removing elements from the DOM does not decrease `listenerCount`.  If you add a listener to a node and then remove that node, the count doesn't go down.  You could hook into `Node.removeChild`, but that doesn't handle removals by `innerHTML`.  This might not be a problem for your situation, but I wanted to make you aware of it.

Comment: Not an accurate answer since removeEventListener and addEventListener call counts may vary and set the variable into negative value.

Comment: @HydraOrc This is definitely a terrible answer now, for both the reasons you and I have identified if the comments here, and because there is now a `getEventListeners` function (which didn't exist in 2012 when I wrote this). Unfortunately, I can't delete this because it's been accepted, but I can at least turn it into a pointer to the much better answer that uses `getEventListeners`. Thanks for bringing this to my attention!

Answer (score 32):

Just use the API `getEventListeners` to get all the events' info. See this link [Chrome Dev Tools : view all event listeners used in the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366849/chrome-dev-tools-view-all-event-listeners-used-in-the-page/45842339#45842339)

> The content of this answer:

The Chrome Devtool can't do this for you. But you can inspect those in your console with the API chrome gives: `getEventListeners`

Just put this code in your dev-tool's console, you can get all the binding click events number in your page:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
  .reduce(function(pre, dom){
    var clks = getEventListeners(dom).click;
    pre += clks ? clks.length || 0 : 0;
    return pre
  }, 0)
```

The result is like this:

```
3249
```

That was a lot of click binding there. Definitely not a good example of project for performance.

If you want see what events have been bound in all your elements in your page and how many of the listeners of each of the events, just put these codes in your dev-tool's console:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
  .reduce(function(pre, dom){
    var evtObj = getEventListeners(dom)
    Object.keys(evtObj).forEach(function (evt) {
      if (typeof pre[evt] === 'undefined') {
        pre[evt] = 0
      }
      pre[evt] += evtObj[evt].length
    })
    return pre
  }, {})
```

The result is like this:

```
{
  touchstart: 6,
  error: 2,
  click: 3249,
  longpress: 2997,
  tap: 2997,
  touchmove: 4,
  touchend: 4,
  touchcancel: 4,
  load: 1
}
```

And so many other info you can get from this API. Just improvise.

Answer (score 6):

You can monitor events in Chrome Developer Tools using the monitorEvents function. See http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/chrome-developer-tools-monitorevents for all the details.