# List event listeners of element

Tags: jquery

Trying to list the event listeners on a website with the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var s = $._data($('.group4.cboxElement')[0], "events")
    console.log(s);
  });
```

However getting `Undefined` on the `console.log()` line.

[This](http://www.cottrellmotors.co.uk/used-PORSCHE-911-Warrington-Cheshire-950810) is the website, I need to see what event listeners are attached to the `<a>` links in the Gallery tab.

**Edit:**
Can someone tell me how to listen the events attached, or remove them that would be great.

Browser: Chrome

Comment: I can't find anything called `_data` in the jQuery API. My guess is that it is a custom function or third-party plugin.

Comment: Using Google Chrome, console.log usually works fine. @ÁlvaroGonzález in that case how do I list the event listeners attached to an object?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález That's a non public jQuery method (internal). It can change from version to version

Comment: Well yes, i'm attempting to figure out what event listener is attached to an object, or remove it. Clearly my code is incorrect.

Comment: using jQuery: 1.7.1

Comment: `jQuery( elem ).data( "events" );` < version 1.8, also check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no official API for doing this.

If your goal is just to do this as part of debugging, Chrome itself can show you the event listeners attached to an element at the DOM level, see [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366849/chrome-dev-tools-view-all-event-listeners-used-in-the-page), and there are Chrome extensions (like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-debugger/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)) that can show you the jQuery event handlers as well (since jQuery maintains its own list of handlers, using only a single handler per event per element).